# Django forms DateTimeInput widget- how to specify max date?

Tags: python, django, forms, date, restrictions

I have a form displayed in my Django project, and one of the form fields is a `DateTimeInput` widget, defined with:

```
    presentation_date = mDateTimeField(required=False, label="Presentation date", widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
```

This widget currently displays all dates between the start of last year to the end of this year (01/01/2016- 31/12/2017). However, at the end of last year this caused some issues, as it meant that users were unable to select dates for the beginning of this year. What I want to do is extend the range of the dates available for selection in the widget by one year (i.e the new range would be 01/01/2016- 31/12/2018).

I understand that it is possible to do this using form validation (for example, by writing a view such as `clean_presentation_date()` and performing the validation inside that view, but this won't solve the issue I'm having- as currently, dates before 01/01/2016 or after 31/12/2017 (displayed in the `datetimepicker` calendar that's shown when the user selects the field in the form) are 'greyed out' and it is not possible to select them. This is exactly the functionality that I want, but I just want to change the values of the dates on which it is performed, so that at least the whole of the next calendar year is always selectable.

I have searched for `maxDate` & `minDate` variables within the `forms.py` file where the form with this field is defined, but can't find anything that looks like it is what's restricting which dates are available to be selected, and which are not selectable.

The `view` that's showing the page with this form on it is defined with:

```
def concept(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('budget_versions').get(id=project_id)
    deposit = Deposit.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    end_details = EndDetails.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentation_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(prefix="presentations", instance=project, queryset=presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'presentations': presentations,
        'presentation_formset': presentation_formset,
        'drawing_formset': drawing_formset,
        'deposit_form': DepositInfoForm(instance=deposit),
        'ended_form': EndDetailsForm(instance=end_details),
        'budget_notes_form': BudgetNotesForm(instance=project.budget_overview),
    }
```

The particular `form` I'm looking at is the `presentations` one, defined in `forms.py`:

```
class FirstPresentationForm(ValidatedForm):
    """ UNUSED """
    who_presenting = forms.CharField()
    details = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Original option costed')
    presentation_date = mDateTimeField(required=False, label="Presentation date", widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) #ERF(19/12/2016 @ 1210) Remove 'datetimepicker' from field..., attrs=({'class':'datetimepicker'})))

    class Meta:
        model = Budget
        fields = ('presentation_date','who_presenting','details')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        who_presenting = [pe.employee.id for pe in project.assigned.select_related('employee').filter(role=Role.P)]
        #Make into an array with two employee IDs, or None. If two results were found, they will already be in the right format
        if len(who_presenting)==1:
            who_presenting.append(None)
        elif not who_presenting:
            who_presenting = None

        if instance.presentation_date:
            pres_meeting, created = Meeting.objects.get_or_create(project=project, purpose='6')
            self.pres_meeting_id = pres_meeting.id
            self.pres_meeting_creator = pres_meeting.event_creator or ''
            if created:
                pres_meeting.date = instance.presentation_date
                pres_meeting.save()

        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial={
                    'who_presenting': who_presenting,
                    }
        kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super(FirstPresentationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['who_presenting'] = AutoFlexiSelect(model='e', required=False, choices=get_choices('DESIGN_EMPLOYEE_CHOICES'), current_id=who_presenting, label="Who is presenting")
        self.fields['presentation_date'].widget.attrs.update({'data-meeting-id': getattr(self,'pres_meeting_id', ''), 'data-meeting-creator': getattr(self,'pres_meeting_creator', '')})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        project = self.instance.project
        data = self.cleaned_data

        try: ProjectEmployee.objects.filter(project=project, role=Role.P).delete() #Delete current records, if any, to prevent build up on editing this field
        except ObjectDoesNotExist: pass
        if data['who_presenting']:
            designers = data['who_presenting']
            # Get the ids from the form field (received as a string)
            designers = [re.sub('\D+', '', s) for s in designers.split(',')]

            who_presenting_1 = Employee.objects.get(id=designers[0])
            who_presenting_2 = designers[1] #If only one employee in selected choice, this will be None
            if who_presenting_2: who_presenting_2 = Employee.objects.get(id=designers[1]) #If two employees in selected choice, sets the second one

            pe = ProjectEmployee(project=project, employee=who_presenting_1, role=Role.P)
            pe.save()

            if who_presenting_2: #If a second designer, delete as well
                pe = ProjectEmployee(project=project, employee=who_presenting_2, role=Role.P)
                pe.save()

        if 'presentation_date' in self.changed_data:
            from events.models import refresh_group_cache
            print '************'
            pres_meeting = Meeting.objects.get(project=project, purpose='6')
            self.instance.meeting = pres_meeting
            self.instance.save()
            print 'Updating date', data['presentation_date'], pres_meeting.id
            pres_meeting.date = data['presentation_date']
            pres_meeting.save()
            refresh_group_cache(pres_meeting.event_creator.calendar_id, pres_meeting.date.year, pres_meeting.date.month, pres_meeting.event_id, pres_meeting)

        return super(FirstPresentationForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

I have tried passing/ setting `max_date` as an attribute of the `presentation_date` variable, but it doesn't appear to have an attribute/ property by this name...

How can I specify a particular date as this `widget`'s `maxDate`, so that the user is able to select dates up until December of next year, rather than just up until December of this year?

**Edit**

The `mDateTimeField` that's using the `widget` is also defined in `forms.py`, with:

```
class mDateTimeField(forms.DateTimeField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('input_formats', DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
        super(mDateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

**This should help you:**

```
widgets = {
    'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class':'datepicker', 'data-min': YOUR_MIN_DATE, 
        'data-max': YOUR_MAX_DATE}),
}
```

**Usage:**

```
minDate: $(this).data('min'),
maxDate: $(this).data('max'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure where I would put this...? Do I need to customise the definition of the `widget` somewhere? I am using `DateTimeInput`, not `DateInput`... don't know if this makes a difference...?

Comment: Yes, you have to customize your widget. And you can use the above code then. Just incorporate the same in your code

Comment: Where do I customise the widget? Isn't it part of Django's built in features? Where would I put the code you've written in your answer? Inside the class `mDateTimeField` in `forms.py`, or inside the parameter of the form instance that I'm creating in the `view`?

Comment: Any further suggestions? As shown by the code in my OP, I am passing a `DateTimeInput` object as a `widget`  into the instance of `mDateTimeField` that I create in the form... the `DateTimeInput` is a different object to the `DateInput` object you are using in your answer...

Comment: Here you go.This is for the widget setup. [Link](https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget)