# Can I limit the dates possibilities using django widget DateInput, ex. between 2020-01-01 and 2023-12-31

Tags: django, django-forms

Using the widget DateInput, I would like to limit the range of dates offered by the datepicker to a set range, for example between Jan. 1, 2020 to Dec. 31, 2023.

I understand, that the date could be validated after it has been entered but is it possible to limit what the user could enter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django forms DateTimeInput widget- how to specify max date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447621/django-forms-datetimeinput-widget-how-to-specify-max-date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) and the example below.

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateField(attrs={'min': '2020-01-01', 'max': '2021-01-01'}))
```

Or in the `__init__`:

```
self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'min': '2020-01-01', 'max': '2021-01-01'})
```

You might want to use a datepicker made by someone else since the HTML5 datepicker might not show on IE or Safari.